# Copying tab labels and values between workbooks

Tags: excel, tabs, copy, label, vba

I've been trying to come up with VBA code in Excel that would allow me to pull values from one workbook and paste them into another. 
Have two workbooks: one is the source of data (with multiple tabs) and the other where I would like to paste values from the source file.

Data source workbook (wb1), I hope you can see the image below

From wb1 I need to copy 3 things: tab label, and values from Columns D and G in row 11 and paste them into sheet in wb2 in the same row. And I am trying to this for each of the available tabs in wb1, copy the three values (tab label, value 1 from D11, value 2 from G11) and paste them over into wb2 so they are stacked in rows.

So my final table would look like this:

Port1    2.78     2.11

Port2    ....     ....

Port3    ....     ....

Port4    ....     ....

And so on. 
I hope that someone will be kind enough and help me out with my issues.

Thank you much in advance.

Comment: ask a specific question

Comment: post the code that you have written so we can help you adjust it where needed

Comment: Sub Import()
Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, p As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Import")
    ws1.Range("data_table").ClearContents
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Data_Source.XLSX")
    For Each ws2 In wb2.Worksheets
        i = i + 1
        n = n + 1
        p = p + 1
        ws.Range("B7:B" & i).Value = ws2.Name
        ws.Range("C7:C" & n).Value = ws2.Cells(11, d)
        ws.Range("D7:D" & p).Value = ws2.Cells(11, g)
Next ws2

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code so far:

Sub Import()

```
Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, p As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Import")
ws1.Range("data_table").ClearContents

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Data_Source.XLSX")

For Each ws2 In wb2.Worksheets
    i = i + 1
    n = n + 1
    p = p + 1
    ws.Range("B7:B" & i).Value = ws2.Name
    ws.Range("C7:C" & n).Value = ws2.Cells(11, d)
    ws.Range("D7:D" & p).Value = ws2.Cells(11, g)


Next ws2
```

End Sub